# body size when you have a window scroll

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have a basic question...
When you have a html page with a scrollbar, the size of the body element remains equal to the window size, not to the effective width of the page inside the window... why?
Is there a way to modify this behaviour?

Comment: which browser on which os? how have you tested that? it seems to me that, if i reduce the size of my browser-window (so i get scrollbars), the body _is_ resized (or it looks like it is, a page like stackoverflow is moving 8px to the left to stay 'centered')

Comment: ie, firefox, safari chrome and opera in windows

Answer (score 1):

I think this only happens if you `float` the contents inside the body, and do not predict for expansion of the container..

If you care to show some code, we might be able to tell you exactly why it happens in your case..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking, but I believe you want NO SCROLLBARS, am I right?

If so, then put this in your CSS

```
html, body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: {whatever width you want}
}
```

Comment: No, having the scrollbar is not a problem...
What I said happens also in this site... if you put a right border to the "body" element and resize the page to have a scrollbar, you'll see that the border cuts the page... because the body element has the width of the window...

Answer (score 0):

I can't say why exactly it's happening, but you can use CSS "min-width" instruction to overcome this behavior. Hope it helps.